# Request canceled when downloading feed

Tags: c#, rest, azure

I have a worker role on Azure. Every two hours, i download products from 3 different affiliate company.

First time, when the job runs, it's works perfect. The next time the job should run, I get from one affiliate, "The request was aborted: The request was canceled." The 2 others works perfect.

It's not just once, every time. I have ask this affiliate company, but there is no problem. So it must be my code. I have this to download json doc:

```
        using (var Client = new WebClient())
        {
            Client.Headers.Add("X-API-KEY", Key);
            Data = Client.DownloadString(URL);
        }
```

What have I missed?

**UPDATE 1:**

i have try this:

```
        HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        Req.KeepAlive = false;
        Req.Headers.Add("X-API-KEY", Key);
        Req.Method = "GET";

        using (var Resp = Req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var Reader = new StreamReader(Resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                Data = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Same problem.

**UPDATE 2**

Request 1

```
GET https://se.#####.com/1/stores.json HTTP/1.1
X-API-KEY: x.............N
Host: se.#####.com
Connection: Close
```

Response 1

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 14:56:39 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: ci_session=..............; expires=Mon, 08-Jun-2015 16:56:39 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/

e30
{"status":true,"data":[................]}
0
```

Request 2

```
GET https://se.#####.com/1/stores.json HTTP/1.1
X-API-KEY: x.............N
Host: se.#####.com
Connection: Close
```

Response 2

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 15:06:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: ci_session=..................; expires=Mon, 08-Jun-2015 17:06:29 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/

e30
{"status":true,"data":[.....................]}
0
```

UPDATE 3

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DownloadTest()
    {
          Test();
          Test();
          Test();
    }


    private static void Test()
    {
        const string merchantsUrl = "https://se.#####.com/1/stores.json";
        string Data;

        var Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(merchantsUrl);
        Req.KeepAlive = false;
        Req.Headers.Add("X-API-KEY", ".....");
        Req.Method = "GET";

        using (var Resp = Req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var Reader = new StreamReader(Resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                Data = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the order of requests and see if the request to same company is failing?
2. **By default WebClient opens a connection as KeepAlive which might be causing this issue. So try explicitly mentioning that KeepAlive mode is false.**
3. Capture the request details for the first time and second time in fiddler or similar tools which could give you more details in tracking down the issue.

Comment: 1. Yes, i have tried that, same problem.
2. Updated my question with another try i did.
3. I try fiddler on my pc, and i get the same response(json) from the affiliate company. 
But on the second time i get, "The request was aborted: The request was canceled." in my service.

Comment: Can you please check the fiddler on your first and seconds requests rather than on responses, to figure out how differently your second request is being made?

Comment: Yes, i cant find any different. I updated my question with information from fiddler, se UPDATE 2.

Comment: It looks crazy. But one last try I would like to do is - Through any rest client like Fiddler or PostMan on chrome, try to hit the same failing service that you were doing. Do it manually from there twice and see if that goes.

Comment: I notice one thing in Fiddler when i run the work, i se a red icon on the request i get the error on in my code.

There is no problem with PostMan. I update my question, when i try UPDATE 3, i get no errors.

Comment: I think i found the problem. In one of the other 2 request i do to the affiliate companies. I forgot to set KeepAlive = false;  Now, the error is gone.